# NX workspace - angular 14 - jest not working

Tags: ts-jest, nrwl-nx, angular14

I'm trying to upgrade my angular 13 NX workspaces to angular 14, but somehow I can't get my jest unit tests to work properly. I tried the following from zero:

Install `@angular/cli` and `nx` globally:

```
npm install --global @angular/cli@latest
npm install --global nx@latest
```

Open and cmd in a path without spaces

```
npx create-nx-workspace
> test
> angular
> demo
> scss
```

Result:

> Nx is creating your v13.10.5 workspace

So now I could migrate to the latest NX workspace version

```
cd test
nx migrate latest
```

The `@angular/cli` version is still on 13, so I changed this in the root `package.json` to `14.0.1` (nx removes the version annotations `~` and `^`...)

`npm install` doesn't work out. `jest-preset-angular@11.1.2` requires `@angular-devkit/build-angular@">=0.1002.4"` while in the workspace this is a dependency fixed at `@angular-devkit/build-angular@"14.0.1"`:

```
npm ERR! Found: @angular-devkit/build-angular@13.3.7
npm ERR! node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-angular
npm ERR!   dev @angular-devkit/build-angular@"14.0.1" from the root project
npm ERR!   peer @angular-devkit/build-angular@">=0.1002.4" from jest-preset-angular@11.1.1
npm ERR!   node_modules/jest-preset-angular
npm ERR!     dev jest-preset-angular@"11.1.2" from the root project
```

So I run update instead:

```
npm update
npx nx migrate --run-migrations
```

I'm able to run the project

```
npm start -- --open
```

Before we can run the command for the unit tests, add the following `script` under the root `package.json` `scripts` section:

```
{
  ...,
  "scripts: {
    ...,
    "nx": "nx"
  }
}
```

Now I'm unable to run the unit tests:

```
npm run nx run-many -- --target=test --projects=demo --watch=false --browsers=ChromeHeadless

 FAIL   demo  apps/demo/src/app/app.component.spec.ts
  ● Test suite failed to run

    Cannot find module '@angular/core/testing' from '../../node_modules/jest-preset-angular/build/config/setup-jest.js'

    Require stack:
      C:/repos/b/test/node_modules/jest-preset-angular/build/config/setup-jest.js
      C:/repos/b/test/node_modules/jest-preset-angular/setup-jest.js
      src/test-setup.ts

      at Resolver.resolveModule (../../node_modules/jest-resolve/build/resolver.js:324:11)
```

Note that the module is definitely installed:

[image: @angular/core/testing is present in the workspace]

Other Q&A's suggest updating `jest-preset-angular`, so I did. I changed it to `12.1.0` in the package.json. This requires `jest@28.1.1`, so changed that too. And `ts-jest` should be at `28.0.5`.

Running `npm update` succeeds now. But running the unit tests

```
npm run nx run-many -- --target=test --projects=demo --watch=false --browsers=ChromeHeadless
```

now gives the following errors:

```
ReferenceError: document is not defined
NG0200: Circular dependency in DI detected for TestComponentRenderer. Find more at https://angular.io/errors/NG0200
NG0200: Circular dependency in DI detected for InjectionToken DocumentToken. Find more at https://angular.io/errors/NG0200
...
```

It litterally suggests the following:

```
The error below may be caused by using the wrong test environment, see https://jestjs.io/docs/configuration#testenvironment-string.
    Consider using the "jsdom" test environment.
```

So I installed it:

```
npm i --save-dev jest-environment-jsdom
```

And updated the root `jest.config.js`:

```
module.exports = {
  projects: getJestProjects(),
  testEnvironment: 'jest-environment-jsdom'
};
```

This still gives me the same error. I also tried with `testEnvironment: 'jsdom'` without success. So how can I fix this? Or do I have to wait until the NX developers release a new stable version?

Comment: having the same issue. any update on this?

Comment: try setting testEnvironment: 'jsdom', worked for us after upgrading all packages to the latest with that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As of today (like just now...) I was able to upgrade to 14.

```
nx migrate latest
```

Open the root package.json file

- restore the `~` and `^`
- remove the `@angular/eslint` packages which are still on 13
- manually change `@angular/cli` to 14.0.0

Then `npm update` and `npx nx migrate --run-migrations` were working as expected. You'll see warnings about the `tsconfig`. You need to open each library's `project.json` and add

```
"targets:build:options:tsConfig": "libs/my-lib/tsconfig.lib.json"
```

The test section doesn't need modifications, it would say that the `tsconfig` field there is deprecated.

This is my final root `package.json`

```
{
  "name": "mintplayer-ng-bootstrap",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "license": "MIT",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "nx",
    "nx": "nx",
    "postinstall": "node ./decorate-angular-cli.js && ngcc --properties es2020 browser module main",
    "start": "nx serve",
    "build": "nx build",
    "test": "nx test"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "~14.0.2",
    "@angular/cdk": "~14.0.1",
    "@angular/common": "~14.0.2",
    "@angular/compiler": "~14.0.2",
    "@angular/core": "~14.0.2",
    "@angular/forms": "~14.0.2",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~14.0.2",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~14.0.2",
    "@angular/router": "~14.0.2",
    "@mintplayer/ng-pagination": "~14.0.0",
    "@nrwl/angular": "14.3.5",
    "bootstrap": "^5.1.3",
    "bootstrap-icons": "^1.7.2",
    "ngx-highlightjs": "~6.1.1",
    "qrcode": "^1.5.0",
    "rxjs": "~7.4.0",
    "tslib": "^2.0.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.11.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~14.0.2",
    "@angular/cli": "~14.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~14.0.2",
    "@angular/language-service": "~14.0.2",
    "@nrwl/cli": "14.3.5",
    "@nrwl/cypress": "14.3.5",
    "@nrwl/eslint-plugin-nx": "14.3.5",
    "@nrwl/jest": "14.3.5",
    "@nrwl/linter": "14.3.5",
    "@nrwl/workspace": "14.3.5",
    "@types/jest": "27.4.1",
    "@types/node": "16.11.7",
    "@types/qrcode": "^1.4.2",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "~5.24.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "~5.24.0",
    "cypress": "^9.1.0",
    "eslint": "~8.15.0",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "8.1.0",
    "eslint-plugin-cypress": "^2.10.3",
    "jest": "27.5.1",
    "jest-preset-angular": "11.1.2",
    "ng-packagr": "^14.0.2",
    "postcss": "^8.4.5",
    "postcss-import": "^14.1.0",
    "postcss-preset-env": "^7.5.0",
    "postcss-url": "^10.1.3",
    "prettier": "^2.6.2",
    "ts-jest": "27.1.4",
    "typescript": "~4.7.3",
    "nx": "14.3.5"
  }
}
```

The related project is hosted [here](https://github.com/MintPlayer/mintplayer-ng-bootstrap)